# Is there a shorter syntax than soup.select("#visitor_stats")[0]?

Tags: beautifulsoup

I'm using BeautifulSoup (`import bs4`) to read some information from a web page. Several lines in my script look like

```
stats = soup.select("#visitor_stats")[0]
```

Is there a shorter syntax for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`select()`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors) lets you select a bunch of HTML tag elements based on their CSS properties (like `id` and `class`). In this case you are looking for all HTML tag elements with CSS `id` property set to `visitor_stats`. And then selecting the first element from the returned list.

The BeautifulSoup method [`find()`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find) returns the first occurrence of the search criteria. So the list index `[0]` can be gotten rid of by using `find()`

```
stats = soup.find(attrs={'id':'visitor_stats'})
```

But I am not sure if this is any shorter :)

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. Guess the syntax I have is shortest. Surprised that there's `find` and `find_all`, but `select` doesn't have any analogous `select_all`.

Comment: Usually `find` is used when you know the HTML tag name. In your case I think CSS selector is more apt since the selection is based on a CSS property and not on a tag name.